# html to pdf on Azure using pdfkit with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I'm attempting to write an Azure function which converts an html input to pdf and either writes this to a blob and/or returns the pdf to the client. I'm using the [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) python library. This requires the wkhtmltopdf executable to be available.

To test this locally on my windows machine, I installed the windows version of wkhtmltopdf and this works completely fine.

When I deployed this function on a Linux app service on Azure, I could still execute the function successfully only after I execute the sudo command on kudo tools to install wkhtmltopdf on the app service.

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

I'm also aware that I can write this start up script on the app service itself.

My question is : Is there something I can do on my local windows machine so I can just deploy the the azure function along with the linux version of wkhtmltopdf directly from my vscode without having to execute another script on the app service itself?

Comment: I've answered (and updated my answer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75068513/execute-sudo-commands-as-part-of-startup-on-azure-linux-app-service/75186747#75186747

Answer (score 0):

By setting the below commands in the App configuration will work.

Thanks to @pamelafox for the comments.

**Commands**

`PRE_BUILD_COMMAND` or `POST_BUILD_COMMAND`

The following process is applied for each build.

1. Run custom command or script if specified by  `PRE_BUILD_COMMAND`  or  `PRE_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH`.
2. Create python virtual environment if specified by  `VIRTUALENV_NAME`.
3. Run  `python -m pip install --cache-dir /usr/local/share/pip-cache --prefer-binary -r requirements.txt`  if  `requirements.txt`  exists in the root of repo or specified by  `CUSTOM_REQUIREMENTSTXT_PATH`.
4. Run  `python setup.py install`  if  `setup.py`  exists.
5. Run python package commands and determine python package wheel.
6. If  `manage.py`  is found in the root of the repo  `manage.py collectstatic`  is run. However, if  `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`  is set to  `true`  this step is skipped.
7. Compress virtual environment folder if specified by  `compress_virtualenv`  property key.
8. Run custom command or script if specified by  `POST_BUILD_COMMAND`  or  `POST_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH`.

### Build Conda environment and Python JupyterNotebook

The following process is applied for each build.

1. Run custom command or script if specified by  `PRE_BUILD_COMMAND`  or  `PRE_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH`.
2. Set up Conda virtual environemnt  `conda env create --file $envFile`.
3. If  `requirment.txt`  exists in the root of repo or specified by  `CUSTOM_REQUIREMENTSTXT_PATH`, activate environemnt  `conda activate $environmentPrefix`  and run  `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`.
4. Run custom command or script if specified by  `POST_BUILD_COMMAND`  or  `POST_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH`.

### Package manager

The latest version of  `pip`  is used to install dependencies.

Run

The below process is applied to know how to start an app.

1. If user has specified a start script, run it.
2. Else, find a WSGI module and run with  [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/).

   1. Look for and run a directory containing a  `wsgi.py`  file (*for Django*).
   2. Look for the following files in the root of the repo and an  `app`  class within them (*for Flask*  and other WSGI frameworks).

      - `application.py`
      - `app.py`
      - `index.py`
      - `server.py`

#### Gunicorn multiple workers support

To enable running gunicorn with multiple  [workers strategy](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers)  and fully utilize the cores to improve performance and prevent potential timeout/blocks from sync workers, add and set the environment variable  `PYTHON_ENABLE_GUNICORN_MULTIWORKERS=true`  into the app settings.

In Azure Web Apps the version of the Python runtime which runs your app is determined by the value of  `LinuxFxVersion`  in your  [site config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/get#siteconfig). See  [../base_images.md](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/base_images.md#azure-web-apps-runtimes-and-versions)  for how to modify this.

References taken from

[Python runtime on App Service](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/runtimes/python.md#run)