# Execute sudo commands as part of startup on Azure linux app service

Tags: linux, azure, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

We have a requirement to generate pdfs from html. We are using pdfkit which requires the wkhtmltopdf package.

```
import logging import azure.functions as func import time import pdfkit import os

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    pdf_bytes = give_me_pdf()
    return func.HttpResponse(pdf_bytes, mimetype='application/pdf')
        
def give_me_pdf(package):
    with open('comb_template.html') as f:
        pdf_bytes = pdfkit.from_file(f)
    return pdf_bytes
```

When I deploy my code to Azure Linux App service, I need to SSH into my server and fire the `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` command to manually install the package into my linux  app service.

Is there a way to do this via some startup script so that this happens automatically when I deploy to Azure app service?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting either PRE_BUILD_COMMAND or POST_BUILD_COMMAND in the App configuration settings.

For more details, here's a document about the process used for the Python runtime on App Service:
https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/runtimes/python.md#build